# NetSuite Employee Subsidiary Change

Tags: netsuite

I have an requirement to move employees from one subsidiary to another. However, that field is greyed out. I need to maintain the same employee record as it is integrated to other systems. I do not want to create a new employee record.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please try yourself first and then ask for help if you have troubles.  This is not a code-generation site.

Comment: Are you trying to do this on the NetSuite web interface or programmatically, e.g. by using web services?

Answer (score 2):

Directly from the NetSuite Help page entitled "Adding an Employee":

> After a transaction has posted for the employee, you are not able to change the selected subsidiary on the employee record.

That means if you have *any* transactions (e.g. paychecks) associated with an employee, you can no longer change its subsidiary.

Subsidiary is not an available field in Employee Mass Updates either, and it is doubtful that a script will be able to change it either.

In general, it is very difficult to change subsidiary on most record types because of the accounting and financial implications. I believe at this point your only option is creating new Employee records and updating the integrated system.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, I would create a new employee record in the new subsidiary.  This keeps record keeping quite consistent and leaves the history/audit trail.

Simply make the "old" employee record inactive and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the employee input form and find out if the subsidiary field is disabled or set to "inline text" - if it is change it to normal then save the form. Once the form is saved them the field should be accessible.